# Do I have to manually reset shared_ptrs in my own destructors?

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor, shared-ptr

Say I have a class like

```
class A {
public: // I know, I know...
    shared_ptr<string> aString;
};
```

do I have to have a destructor like

```
~A() {
    aString.reset();
}
```

to ensure that ownership is properly reliquished? I did a few tests, and it would seem that I do not have to — i.e., when an instance of A goes out of scope or is deleted (or reset, if I reference it through a shared_ptr), the string is deleted as well (I played with a more sophisticated example to confirm this). However, this could be implementation specific to the compiler that I am using (clang-700.0.72).

My question is: is this always the case, or is it better to explicitly reset those instances like I would delete any other dumb pointer?

Comment: You should consider what you need in the copy ctor and assignment. By default, you'll get a second shared pointer to the same object, with an increased share count (shallow copy). If you need a deep copy, you have to arrange that yourself. (Unusual, because the whole point about shared_ptr is sharing, and a deep copy means no sharing).

Comment: Yes, if I need to share ownership – short- or long-term – I would expect to get all the use counts raised by one. In the particular case that triggered my question, I have a class that likely will only ever have one owner, but that needs to strongly hold on to that member – which also means that the pointer in my real case is never going to be used outside of the class, and even if it does, it will at least be +1'd against accidental deletions (which I know are unlikely to happen anyway because this is not library code :)

Comment: Wouldn't you be better of using `std::unique_ptr` in that case, and handing out references? If anybody is going to call `delete` on a reference, I believe you're entitled to do a Linus Torvalds imitation

Comment: I supposed I could, indeed. My brain is heavily debating whether I want to err on the safe side, or be required to raise several fingers at uncomfortably high rates in the future :)

Comment: When your fellow coders are deleting references, you should think more about _amputating_ fingers than raising them. Limits the harm done ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that's the main point of smart pointers: **to manage memory automatically**.

The destructor of `shared_ptr` will automatically decrease the reference count, and if it reaches 0, will call the deleter.

If you don't provide a destructor, a default one will be generated:

> **§ 12.4.4** If a class has no user-declared destructor, a destructor is implicitly declared as defaulted

The destruction of your class will guarantee the destruction of members.

> **§ 12.4.8** After executing the body of the destructor and destroying any automatic objects allocated within the body, a destructor for class X calls the destructors for X's direct non-variant non-static data members(...)

Which in turn for `shared_ptr` means:

> **§ 20.8.2.2.2.1**
>
> `~shared_ptr();`
>
> Effects:
>
> - If *this is empty or shares ownership with another shared_ptr instance (use_count() > 1), there are no side effects.
> - Otherwise, if *this owns an object p and a deleter d, d(p) is called.
> - Otherwise, *this owns a pointer p, and delete p is called.

This behaviour is nicely summarized as [The Rule Of Zero](https://rmf.io/cxx11/rule-of-zero/).

Comment: Is name calling and then editing your post to incorporate their point accepted StackOverflow form?

Comment: Although I don't condone name-calling, I can see where that came from. You called something "total nonsense" without providing any further clarification. The Internet is full of answers like that, and they are unhelpful and irritating to most. @Bartek, I think your last sentence could benefit from clarifying that point about the compiler filling in the missing destruction calls. It makes the whole thing a bit more explicit, thus clearer.

Comment: @Morpheu5 I've added the standard references for the default-dtor behaviour.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The ctor will indeed call the member destructors, if an exception is thrown ;) Seriously, this can be confusing if you're troubleshooting build problems and can't figure out why those member dtors are needed from the ctor.

Comment: **FTR** the first statement I made was just a simple typo ("constructor" when I meant "destructor"). I got annoyed because it was called nonsense, misunderstood what LRiO said and called him a "smartass pedant", which I shouldn't and I apologize for that.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: I accept your apology. Have a nice day!

Comment: @Morpheu5: Bartek is a well-known and knowledgeable individual. I had complete confidence that he is capable of identifying the problem in his post when it was correctly identified as nonsense. Butting in to judge as a third party, without context, is unhelpful and irritating to most.

Comment: @LRiO I see everything is good. However, as a third party, I don't know either of you, and as a third party, I don't know if that exchange was well-spirited or not. For all I knew, it was one who wrote something nonsensical, another who pointed the nonsense without further clarification, and the first one who resorted to name-calling before even attempting at rectifying. This, to me as a third party, read as juvenile and unhelpful. I'm just saying, this is a public-facing site, not a private mailing list. I'm glad the whole thing was resolved, but I would still honestly question behaviour.

Answer (score 8):

No, you do not need to do so.  As part of the normal destructor, each member of the class will be destroyed in turn.  The destructor for a smart pointer will take care of the necessary accounting, which in this case is an implicit `reset`.

Answer (score 3):

No. This is well-defined and there are no compiler bugs that I'm aware of.